# Library to parse Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, python-2to3

I'm looking for a library that allows parsing and modification of Python 3 source code. There is the built-in [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module, but that doesn't allow parsing Python 3 code from Python 2 and vice versa.

Is there such a library, or a way to make the `ast` module recognize Python 2 code on Python 3?

Comment: How does 2to3 work? That must have some way of handling Python 2 and 3 code.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: @LennartRegebro I want to preprocess source code (similar to minification, for example resolving local imports and applying compatibility code for Python 2.5 and even older platforms), and possibly implement [2to6](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg289271.html).

Comment: Well, Implementing 2to6 is exactly what lib2to3 is for.

Comment: I could also note that I really do want a 2to6 set of fixers, so please make that. :-) Put it on github and I might even help.

Answer (score 3):

Python's lib2to3 library includes a code parser can can parse both Python 2 and Python 3 code. It's not well documented though. [This chapter from the porting book](http://python3porting.com/fixers.html) provides an introduction. If you want to modify code (refactoring, maybe) then [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) could very well be exactly what you are looking for.